# Installing tomcat 7 on Ubuntu Server 12.04

Tags: 12.04, server, tomcat

I'm trying to install tomcat 7 on Ubuntu Server 12.04 with:

```
sudo apt-get install tomcat7
```

which most sites and guides tell to do, but immediately I receive this answer:

```
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done 
Some packages could not be installed. 
This may mean that you have  requested an impossible situation or 
if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages 
have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. 
The following information may help to resolve the situation.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
tomcat7 : Depends: tomcat7-common (>= 7.0.26-1ubuntu1.1) but it is not
going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

**What does this mean?**

I've tried updating the repositories, changing them of country, repairing broken-packages.

I know there is the possibility of manual installation but this should be working easily

Any leads on this are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 10):

This is because the package tomcat6-common is still residing in the system.

do this

```
sudo apt-get remove tomcat6-common
```

This will remove the conflicting package. Installing Tomcat7 Should work fine now

Comment: How will this affect the installed tomcat6? Will it stop working?

Comment: @Rishin This doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I haven't tomcat 6 installed on my system before.
I fixed it by manually installing `libtomcat7-java`. (At first I want to install `tomcat7-common` manually and it complains about `libtomcat7-java`)

Answer (score 0):

Check which packages you had on hold for apt-get, you should use

```
sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep hold
```

The “hold” package state for apt-get can be changed using:

```
sudo echo package_name hold | dpkg --set-selections
```

Replace hold with install to unset the “hold” state

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And then try to install it again.

Comment: The first line didn´t get any packages. I even checked them one by one in case the grep was wrong but every packged is marked as "install"

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had previously installed Tomcat 6, which was conflicting but not being picked up for some reason.